# Picard group of non reduced scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let X be a non reduced scheme. $X_{red}$ be the reduced scheme. Is it true that Picard group of $X_{red}$=Picard group of X?

Is this map surjective $Pic (X)\rightarrow Pic(X_{red})$?

Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Suppose $X_{red}$ is a honest (say smooth, projective, complex) variety $V$, and the ideal $\mathcal{I}$ of $V$ in $X$ has square $0$. There is an  exact sequence (for the Zariski topology)
$$0\rightarrow \mathcal{I}\xrightarrow{\ u\ } \mathcal{O}_X^*\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_V^*\rightarrow 1$$with $u(f)=1+ f$. Taking cohomology gives
$$0\rightarrow H^1(V,\mathcal{I})\rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(X)\rightarrow \operatorname{Pic}(V)\rightarrow H^2(V,\mathcal{I})\rightarrow \ldots   $$So if  $H^1(V,\mathcal{I})\neq 0$ (which is easy to realize), the map is not injective.

Comment: ... However surjectivity seems to be more subtle, I need to think about it.

Comment: By abx's comment above, if $X$ is an affine scheme, then $\mathrm{Pic}(X) \to \mathrm{Pic}(X_{\mathrm{red}})$ is an isomorphism since both $H^{1}(X,\mathcal{I})$ and $H^{2}(X,\mathcal{I})$ are $0$. You may also be interested in [Tag 0C6S](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C6S).

Comment: Yes, but since $\mathcal{I}^2=0$, $\mathcal{I}$ is actually a $\mathcal{O}_V$-module, and $H^i(X,\mathcal{I})=H^i(V,\mathcal{I})$.

Comment: Here $\mathcal{O}_X=\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}[I]$. Let L be a line bundle on $X_{red}$. Then $L[I]$ is a line bundle on $\mathcal{O}_X$, which restricts to be L on $X_{red}$. So the picard level map should be surjective

Comment: Then one can check if L is ample so is $L[I]$...so if $X_{red}$ is projective X is quasi projective. Is this correct??

Comment: I don't understand your comments. What do you mean by $\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}[I]$? There is a homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}$, not the other way around.

Comment: as you said $I $ is a $\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}$-module. We can construct a ring $\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}[I]:=\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}\oplus I$ on which the  ring structure is $(a,b)\cdot (c,d):=(ac,ad+bc)$ and this $\mathcal{O}_{X_{red}}[I]=\mathcal{O}_X$..similarly we can define $L[I]$ please reply

Comment: If you take a hypersurface  $X\subset\mathbb{P}^3$ andlet $X_n$ the $n^{th}$ order thickening, Grothendieck has proved that the inverse limit of $\mathrm{Pic}\, X_n=\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{O}(1)$. Thus, if the Picard group of $X$ is not $\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{O}(1)$ (for example, a smooth quadric), then $\mathrm{Pic}\, X_n\to\mathrm{Pic}\, X$ is not surjective for some $n$.

Comment: ok understood...But if $H^i(X,\mathcal{O})=0$ for $i>0$...then since the obstruction to extend a line bundle L belongs to $H^2(X,End L)=H^2(X, \mathcal{O})$...so it is unobstructed...in that case this map will be surjective

Comment: For quadrics $H^2(X,\mathcal{O})=0$, but the map is not surjective. The vanishing of your obstruction is for extending to $k[\epsilon]$, not thickenings.