# Lefschetz trace formula over truncated Witt ring

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be a finite field, $W_n(k)$ be its $n$-th truncated Witt ring. We have a Frobenius on $W_n(\bar{k})$ whose fixed point is exactly $W_n(k)$. Let $X$ be a finite type separated scheme over $W_n(k)$, do we have a Lefschetz trace formula describing $\#X(W_n(k))$ by traces of geometric Frobenius on $X_{W_n(\bar k)}$'s $\ell$-adic etale cohomology with compact support?

It's true that etale site is unchanged after closed immersion with nilpotent ideal, but the sheaf may change. For example, in general $H^1(X, \Bbb G_m) \not = H^1(X_{red},\Bbb G_m)$ (see [Picard group of non reduced scheme](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278863/picard-group-of-non-reduced-scheme)).

Motivation: if $X$ is smooth over $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$, then we have $\#X(\Bbb Z/p^n \Bbb Z)=\#X(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z) p^{(n-1)\text{dim}(X)}$ for which I hope to find a cohomological explanation. This is related to Igusa zeta function, and I also want to understand $\#X(\Bbb Z/p^n \Bbb Z)$ for non-smooth $X$.

Comment: You can apply the usual Lefschetz trace formula over $k$ to the Greenberg spaces of $X/W_n$.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: For constant coefficients the sheaf will not change, so what Jason Starr suggests is probably the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you, I didn't find a reference for the Greenberg spaces, do you mean Weil restriction. My motivation is edited as above.

Comment: There is no Weil restriction, since $W_n(k)\to k$ is not split.  The analogue of Weil restriction are the Greenberg spaces.  I do not remember a reference out of the top of my head, but these spaces are used in Lang's thesis (where he proves the maximal unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is a $C_1$ field).

Comment: I just read in the Notices of the AMS that Greenberg passed away recently.

Comment: That's very sad, but his mathematical writings and theorems remains forever.